# Read files from hdfs - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark, when I execute the below code, I am getting attribute error.

I am using apache spark 2.4.3

```
t=spark.read.format("hdfs:\\test\a.txt")
t.take(1)
```

I expect the output to be 1, but it throws error.

```
AttributeError: dataframereader object has no attribute take
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the API properly:

- [`format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.format) is used to specify the input data source format you want

Here, you're reading text file so all you have to do is:

```py
t = spark.read.text("hdfs://test/a.txt")
t.collect()
```

See related [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text)

Comment: I have tried the code which you suggest, but i am getting invalid syntax error.

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: val t=spark.read.text("hdfs://karthi/a.txt")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    val t=spark.read.text("hdfs://karthi/a.txt")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: My bad, `val` is mandatory for Scala. You don’t need it for pyspark indeed. Updated my answer. Try without the val.

Comment: Look at the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text) in the pyspark doc. It's really similar to what I suggested. It should work, or you have another issue somewhere else.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did it work for you? Did you find a solution?